# Javascript - confirmation dialog after form submission

Tags: javascript

I am not a Javascript wiz so need some help with the following. I have a popup asking people to type in their email address. Right now the popup just closes after submission, which isn't a nice user experience. Ideally the text bar and the submission button would disappear, and be replaced by a short comment such as "Thanks, we'll be in touch". Even better would be if the popup would then disappear after "N" seconds.

[image: Screenshot]

Can anyone help?

```
    var self = this;
var showDelay = parseInt('[[ bannerShowDelayInMilliseconds ]]' || '0', 10);
setTimeout(function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        if (!self.inPreview && "true" == "{{ 'true' if customer.email else 'false' }}") {
            return;
        }
        self.sdk.track('banner', getEventProperties('show', false));
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', self.html);
        var banner = self.banner = document.querySelector('.exponea-subscription-dialog');
        self.backdrop = document.querySelector('.exponea-subscription-dialog + .exponea-banner-backdrop');
        banner.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<style>' + self.style + '</style>');
        var form = banner.querySelector('form');
        form.onsubmit = function () {
            var eventProperties = getEventProperties('subscribe');
            var email = (form.email.value || '').toLowerCase();
            eventProperties.subscription_email = email;
            self.sdk.track('banner', eventProperties);
            if (validateEmail(email)) {
                self.sdk.update({
                    email: email
            });
        document.getElementById("dialogue").innerHTML = "Thank you message";    
        setTimeout(function(){ removeBanner(); }, 3000);
        }
        return false;
        };
        var btnClose = banner.querySelector('.exponea-close');
        btnClose.onclick = function () {
            removeBanner();
            self.sdk.track('banner', getEventProperties('close'));
        };
    });
}, showDelay);

function getEventProperties(action, interactive) {
    return {
        action: action,
        banner_id: self.data.banner_id,
        banner_name: self.data.banner_name,
        banner_type: self.data.banner_type,
        variant_id: self.data.variant_id,
        variant_name: self.data.variant_name,
        interaction: interactive !== false ? true : false,
        location: window.location.href,
        path: window.location.pathname
    };
}

function removeBanner() {
    if (self.banner) {
        self.banner.parentNode.removeChild(self.banner);
    }
    if (self.backdrop) {
        self.backdrop.parentNode.removeChild(self.backdrop);
    }
}

function validateEmail(email) {
    return email && /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/.test(email);
}
return {
    remove: removeBanner
};
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood currectly, Do you want the removeBanner() function to happen after 'N' seconds ?

Comment: Yeah, but only after submission and after a Thank you dialogue has been shown.

Comment: I have posted an answer with set timeout for 3 seconds and innerHTML , let me know if you need explanation about those

Comment: Unfortunately the changes show no effect. However, I posted the entire code above, maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
        form.onsubmit = function () {
        var eventProperties = getEventProperties('subscribe');
        var email = (form.email.value || '').toLowerCase();
        eventProperties.subscription_email = email;
        self.sdk.track('banner', eventProperties);
        if (validateEmail(email)) {
            self.sdk.update({
                email: email
            });
        document.getElementById("thankYouIdExample").innerHTML = "Thank you message";    
        setTimeout(function(){ removeBanner(); }, 3000);
        }
        return false;
```

Just make sure to place the `<div id="thankYouIdExample"></div>` at the right place.
Let me know if it works for you m8

Comment: Unfortunately the changes show no effect. However, I posted the entire code above, maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `setTimeout`**

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

```js
form.onsubmit = function() {
    var eventProperties = getEventProperties('subscribe')
    var email = (form.email.value || '').toLowerCase()
    eventProperties.subscription_email = email
    self.sdk.track('banner', eventProperties)
    if(validateEmail(email)) {
        self.sdk.update({
            email: email
        })
        setTimeout(() => {
            alert("Thatnk You") // you may want to replace it with a own dialogue system
            removeBanner()
        }, 5000) // wait 5000 milliseconds or in other words 5 seconds

    }
    return false
}
```

Asynchronous version (if you want to return after the 5000 wait):

***only useful if you not directly call the handler**

```js
form.onsubmit = async function() {
    return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var eventProperties = getEventProperties('subscribe')
        var email = (form.email.value || '').toLowerCase()
        eventProperties.subscription_email = email
        self.sdk.track('banner', eventProperties)
        if(validateEmail(email)) {
            self.sdk.update({
                email: email
            })
            setTimeout(() => {
                alert("Thatnk You") // you may want to replace it with a own dialogue system
                removeBanner()
                resolve()
            }, 5000) // wait 5000 milliseconds or in other words 5 seconds
        }
        else reject()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your thanks message in another container, and write something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="form">
        here is the form and everything that belongs here
    </div>
    <div id="thanks">
        here is the thanks message
    </div>
</div>
```

With this, you can set the default style of the thanks div to `display: none;` in css.
If you reference the container divs in js by their ids, you can change their style from js. The `setTimeout()` method can be used to time the closing of the dialog box, assuming it is done by the `removeBanner()` function. You can add these lines:

```
form.onsubmit = function () {
            var eventProperties = getEventProperties('subscribe');
            var email = (form.email.value || '').toLowerCase();
            eventProperties.subscription_email = email;
            self.sdk.track('banner', eventProperties);
            if (validateEmail(email)) {
                self.sdk.update({
                    email: email
                });
                document.getElementById("form").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("thanks").style.display = 'block';
                setTimeout(function(){removeBanner();}, 5000);
            }
            return false;
```

This way you can have a fully pre-customized thanks message.

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for this. Somehow I can't make the button and the input field disappear. They just remain there. I think it's the HTML that's not right.

Comment: <div class="subscription-dialog">
    <span class="exponea-header">[[ headerText ]]</span>
    <span class="exponea-text">[[ bodyText ]]</span>
    <form>
        <input name="email" type="text" class="exponea-input" placeholder="email@example.com" pattern="^\S+@\S+\.\S+$" title="email address in form 'email@example.com'">
        <input type="submit" class="exponea-button" value="[[ buttonTitle ]]" />
    </form>
    <span class="exponea-close"><span class="exponea-close-cross"></span></span>
    <span class="dialogue">[[ dialogue ]]</span>
</div>
<div class="banner-backdrop"></div>